# Android :understanding the download process

Tags: android, download, wifi, inputstream

I'm trying to compute my wifi speed. So i'm downloading a file from a server (10 Mb ). Well the download is working pretty well. But i'm not sure how to cmpute the download spped of every received data packet.

This a part of the code i'm using. I woud like to understand the difference between the two sizes : 8192 and the 1024 ,the purpse of every size .

```
 InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
```

And this line

```
 byte data[] = new byte[1024];
```

And this how i used them :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    int lenghtOfFile = 0;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        comm = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
         lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

     byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            actuaStartlTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            total += count;

}}
```

---

This is a sample of output :curret time and downloaded data. I don't see any relatiosheep between the size of downloaded data.

```
    05-06 15:32:36.883: I/downloaded data(13146): 244392
05-06 15:32:36.883: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386756881
05-06 15:32:37.329: I/downloaded data(13146): 245840
05-06 15:32:37.329: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386757328
05-06 15:32:37.331: I/downloaded data(13146): 247288
05-06 15:32:37.332: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386757330
05-06 15:32:37.334: I/downloaded data(13146): 250184
05-06 15:32:37.334: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386757333
05-06 15:32:37.347: I/downloaded data(13146): 251632
05-06 15:32:37.347: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386757345
05-06 15:32:37.349: I/downloaded data(13146): 262144
05-06 15:32:37.349: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386757348
05-06 15:32:37.637: I/downloaded data(13146): 288208
05-06 15:32:37.637: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386757636
05-06 15:32:38.050: I/downloaded data(13146): 289656
05-06 15:32:38.050: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386758049
05-06 15:32:38.063: I/downloaded data(13146): 298344
05-06 15:32:38.063: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386758062
05-06 15:32:38.067: I/downloaded data(13146): 304136
05-06 15:32:38.068: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386758066
05-06 15:32:38.070: I/downloaded data(13146): 309928
05-06 15:32:38.071: I/current time in millisecond(13146): 1399386758069
05-06 15:32:38.079: I/downloaded data(13146): 317168
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Now is the time to see for yourself if these buffer sizes influence download speed. I think they do. Please try out and make a table with sizes and times.

Comment: Thank you for replying .@greenapps please my post again ,i added a table.

Comment: That does not look like a table. And you did not explain which values you printed. I asked for a table where you used different sizes for your buffer in new byte[1024]; Try with 2048 then download and measure the time. Then change to 4096 and download and measure time again. Increase buffersize. Do the same for the 8192 in (url.openStream(), 8192).